# How do I schedule an alarm for particular days in a week on Android?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarm

I have this method. If I set the alarm within a day, it works fine. I need schedule an alarm for particular days in a week/month/year on Android.

```
public static void setAlarmFragment(int intervalDays, Context context, Calendar targetCal) {

    if (targetCal != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrescriptionAlarmActivity.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int uniqueId = CommonUtils.generateRandomID();
        intent.putExtra("uniqueId", uniqueId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, uniqueId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int i = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            if (intervalDays > 0) {
                long customAlarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * intervalDays;
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), customAlarmInterval, pendingIntent);
                Log.e("AlarmBroadcastReceiver", "Alarm set: " + CommonUtils.getAlarmTime(targetCal));
            }
            else {
                if (i < 19) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                }
                else if (i < 23) {
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                }
                else {
                    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                }
                Log.e("AlarmBroadcastReceiver", "Alarm set: " + CommonUtils.getAlarmTime(targetCal));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. Use ConstraintLayout.
2. Avoid hard-coded layout sizes.

To ensure that your layout is flexible and adapts to different screen sizes, you should use "wrap_content" and "match_parent" for the width and height of most view components, instead of hard-coded sizes.

"wrap_content" tells the view to set its size to whatever is necessary to fit the content within that view.

"match_parent" makes the view expand to as much as possible within the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

One layout, correctly designed, will be available on every device, but it may look strange.

The correct thing to do is first design a landscape layout, and test on different devices, like tablets and low-density smartphones.

Then go for more specific resolutions, like a portrait 7" tablet and a landscape 10.1" tablet.

There you must have achieved almost all screens you need.

If something works good on a smartphone and sucks on another smartphone, you must check how your mail layout XML is designed.

Anyway, you may look for a hdpi resolution if you need a more specific design for low-resolution devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `dimens.xml` file in the `res` folder:

[image]